# Python Unittest: Unit test the message passed in raised exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am unit testing the radius of the circle using unittest framework in Python. If the radius is not a numeric value, then I raise and exception with a custom message.

File: circle.py

```
class Circle():

    def __init__(self, radius):
        if not isinstance (radius, (int,float)):
            raise TypeError('radius must be a number')
        else:
            self.radius = radius
```

File: test_circle.py

```
import unittest
from circle import Circle

class CircleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_radius(self):
        c1 = Circle(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(c1.radius, 2.5)

    def test_radius_type(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, Circle, 'hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Now, I can check the raised exception. But, I also want to find if the message passed in the exception is the exact message or not. Could anyone please guide me how to test and check the message passed in the exception in unittest in Python?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises? Also note your logic seems suspicious - *everything* will be treated as a non-number.

Comment: Don't use `type`; use `if isinstance(radius, (int, float))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check the error message in the exception, you need to capture the exception.

```
def test_radius_type(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as exc:
        c = Circle('hello')
    self.assertEquals(str(exc.exception), "radius must be a number")
```

That said, a custom exception would be cleaner.

```
class NotANumberError(TypeError):
    pass


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        try:
            self.radius = float(radius)
        except ValueError:
            raise NotANumberError


...

def test_radius_type(self):
    self.assertRaises(NotANumber, Circle, 'hello')
```

The type of the exception itself carries the same information as an arbitrary error message.

Comment: I had checked the official docs. I was trying to match the string in assertRaises(TypeError, Circle, 'hello', 'radius must be a number') as per VSCode suggestion. I also tried putting self.assertEquals() inside self.assertRaises(), but now understood the issue with indentation. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me. When i `print(str(exc))` i get `<unittest.case._AssertRaisesContext object at 0x109fb4280>`

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) from @jonrsharpe 's comment above, you have to use `exc.exception` to get the actual exception.
`print(str(exc.exception))` yields the actual error message for me

Comment: Ah, ok. `exc` isn't actually an exception, but a context manager that contains the caught exception.